# Reverse order of discrete y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Situation & data**

I have a dataframe `df` of athlete positions in a race:

```
df <- structure(list(athlete = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
"H", "I", "J", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H", "I", "J", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", 
"J"), distanceRemaining = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("1400m", "1200m", "600m", 
"400m", "200m", "FINISH"), class = "factor"), position = c(10, 
6, 7, 8, 2, 1, 3, 5, 9, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10, 2, 8, 
7, 9, 5, 6, 2, 3, 1, 10, 4, 9, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 4, 10, 1, 4, 
5, 1, 6, 8, 3, 2, 7, 10, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), .Names = c("athlete", "distanceRemaining", "position"), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm plotting the data with

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=distanceRemaining, y =position, colour=athlete, group = athlete))
g <- g + geom_point()
g <- g + geom_line(size=1.15)
g <- g + scale_y_discrete()
g
```

To give

[image: athletePositions]

**Question**

How do I reverse the order of the y-axis so that 10 is at the bottom and 1 is at the top?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

There is a [new](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3115) solution, `scale_*_discrete(limits=rev)`, example:

```
tibble(x=1:26,y=letters) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)
```

[image]

Comment: A different notation could be `scale_y_discrete(limits = \(x) rev(x))`.

Answer (score 55):

as per https://gist.github.com/jennybc/6f3fa527b915b920fdd5:

add `scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(theFactor)))`
to your ggplot command.

Comment: I really like this solution. It doesn't alter or relevel the factor itself (even transiently). Just sets the order of the ticks/labels of the plot directly.

Comment: This only works if you have a factor. Otherwise, I used the `reorder` solution of @David Bloom.

Comment: ggplot has introduced a more elegant solution for this which is described in [Frederik Ziebell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64185647/8366499)

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 42):

Try the following:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=distanceRemaining, y =position, colour=athlete, group = athlete))
g <- g + geom_point()
g <- g + geom_line(size=1.15)
g <- g +  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = unique(df$position))
g
```

[image]

Comment: Can you use `scale_y_reverse()` with `scale_y_discrete()`, or another method to keep the whole numbers on the y axis?

Comment: This doesn't work for me in at least with ggplot2 version 2.1.  `scale_y_continuous` will throw an error if you feed it a factor.  The version to use for a factor would be `scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df$distanceRemaining))` .

Comment: For future people that are stuck, if you had created a group_df with dplyr at some point, you may need to first ungroup your tibble to get the factors in the right order.

Comment: probably the most useful answer is from @Frederik Ziebell

Comment: this to me is the best answer. for larger codebases with lots of conditions, you don't have to have to repeat code by having `scale_y_discrete()` for one scenario, and `scale_y_reverse()` for another. just having an argument you can turn on and off with 'reverse' and 'identity' is extremely useful

Answer (score 40):

For a discrete axis, using reorder() worked for me. In context of the above problem, it would look something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = distanceRemaining, y = reorder(position, desc(position))))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I find this to be the best solution, as it doesn't require to point to anything other than what has been already passed to ggplot. Thank you!

Comment: use `reorder(position -position` should one choose not to use `dplyr`

Answer (score 26):

You just need to turn the position variable into a factor and then reverse its levels:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(position = factor(position), 
                    position = factor(position, levels = rev(levels(position)))
```

And then with your code you'd get:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going with the answer that keeps it within the `ggplot2` call.

Comment: The `trans = "reverse"` approach doesn't work for truly discrete (e.g. character) scales. `scale_y_reverse()` would also have worked since your y-axis can be coerced to a continuous scale...

Comment: you can keep it in the ggplot2 call by `ggplot(df, aes(x=distanceRemaining, y=factor(position, levels=c(1:10)), colour=athlete, group = athlete))`

Comment: Thanks, this solved an annoying problem with `coord_flip()`

Answer (score 10):

Another option using the `forcats` package.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = distanceRemaining, y = forcats::fct_rev(factor(position))))
```

This has the advantage of keeping everything in the `ggplot` call, and playing nicely with other options such as `coord_flip` and `facets_wrap(..., scales = "free")`