# ggplot - order of y axis is not like the one of the dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I got the following data set:

|  | Skalen | Werte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Allgemeine Beanspruchung | 1.55 |
| 2 | Emotionale Beanspruchung | 1.59 |
| 3 | Soziale Beanspruchung | 1.79 |
| 4 | Konflikte/Leistungsdruck | 1.76 |
| 5 | Übermüdung | 1.79 |
| 6 | Energielosigkeit | 2.13 |
| 7 | Somatische Beanspruchung | 1.52 |
| 8 | Erfolg | 2.74 |
| 9 | Soziale Erholung | 3.26 |
| 10 | Somatische Erholung | 3.41 |
| 11 | Allgemeine Erholung | 3.84 |
| 12 | Schlaf | 4.29 |
| 13 | Gestörte Pause | 1.07 |
| 14 | Emotionale Erschöpfung | 1.36 |
| 15 | Verletzungsanfälligkeit | 1.59 |
| 16 | In-Form-sein | 3.28 |
| 17 | Persönliche Verwirklichung | 2.42 |
| 18 | Selbstwirksamkeitsüberzeugung | 3.29 |
| 19 | Selbstregulation | 3.41 |

And I used this code to plot it as a vertical line graph

```
ggplot(data=df_ebf, aes(x=Skalen, y=Werte,group="")) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip()
```

The result is this:
[image]

The values belong to the right description on the y-axis. But the order is reverse alphabetically. I want that the order is like it is in the dataset.

Comment: Try `ggplot(data=df_ebf, aes(x=Skalen, y=forcats::fct_inorder(Werte), group="")) +`

Comment: Alternate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391850/reverse-order-of-discrete-y-axis-in-ggplot2

Comment: I think you'll find that just about every question on stackoverflow that includes [tag:ggplot2] and mentions *"order of axis labels"* (really just *order*) is resolved with the use of `factor` (or thinking columns were already numeric and were strings).

Comment: The answer of @JonSpring helped at least to change the order so that it's not alphabetically ordered anymore. Now it's still reversed, not only the labels but labels and the values have to get reserved

Comment: ok then `forcats::fct_inorder(Werte) %>% forcats::fct_rev`

Comment: If I just add this to the first command line, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a different approach to solve this problem.
I changed the order of the variables in the dataframe with

```
df <- df %>%
  map_df(rev)
```

and then used the first function that Jon Spring suggested in the ggplot command

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=forcats::fct_inorder(Skalen), y=Werte, group="")) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip()
```

Now I got the right order in the plot.

Thanks for the support!