# Reverse order of y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my current code. Trying to figure out how to plot depth of the ocean so 0 needs to be at the top of the axis. Anyone have example code for how to do this?

```
ggplot(data = NH35_6768merge)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(temperature....C., Depth..m., color = Date))
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28391850/5977215 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add:

```
+ scale_y_reverse()
```