Reversing the order in the y-axis in ggplot
I am trying to visualize a regression output. The following code generate a plot where "Urban" is at the top and "Standard Job (ref.)" is at the bottom. How do I create a plot where "Standard Job (ref.)" is on top and "Urban" is at the bottom instead?
Thanks so much for your help.
# Create the odds_ratio_data table based on the provided values
odds_ratio_data <- data.frame(
  Variables = c("Standard Job (ref)", "Precarious job", "Out of labor force", "Unemployed", 
                "Age", "Female", "Non Black and Non Hispanic (ref)", "Black", "Hispanic", 
                "Never Married (ref)", "Married/Cohabiting", "Divorced/Widowed", "Number of children", 
                "Less than High school (ref)", "High school/GED", "College or above", 
                "Both bio parent (ref)", "One bio parent", "Bio and step parent", 
                "Northeast", "North central", "South", "West", "Urban"),
  OddsRatio = c(1, 1.377127764, 1.150273799, 1.616074402, 0.93239382, 0.923116346, 1, 
                1.161834243, 1.733253018, 1, 0.121237966, 0.60653066, 0.826959134, 1, 
                0.93239382, 0.57694981, 1, 0.66365025, 0.486752256, 1, 0.711770323, 0.818730753, 
                0.835270211, 0.711770323),
  LowerCI_OR = c(1, 1.173510871, 1.040810774, 1.404947591, 0.913931185, 0.860707976, 1, 
                 1.051271096, 1.419067549, 1, 0.095369162, 0.516851334, 0.778800783, 1, 
                 0.810584246, 0.491644197, 1, 0.548811636, 0.386741023, 1, 0.637628152, 
                 0.733446956, 0.748263568, 0.637628152),
  UpperCI_OR = c(1, 1.616074402, 1.27124915, 1.858928042, 0.951229425, 0.990049834, 1, 
                 1.284025417, 2.117000017, 1, 0.154123662, 0.711770323, 0.878095431, 1, 
                 1.072508181, 0.677056874, 1, 0.802518798, 0.612626394, 1, 0.786627861, 
                 0.913931185, 0.93239382, 0.786627861)
)

# Define the correct order for the variables, with "Precarious job" at the top and "Urban" at the bottom
correct_order <- c("Standard Job (ref)", "Precarious job", "Out of labor force", "Unemployed", 
                "Age", "Female", "Non Black and Non Hispanic (ref)", "Black", "Hispanic", 
                "Never Married (ref)", "Married/Cohabiting", "Divorced/Widowed", "Number of children", 
                "Less than High school (ref)", "High school/GED", "College or above", 
                "Both bio parent (ref)", "One bio parent", "Bio and step parent", 
                "Northeast", "North central", "South", "West", "Urban")

# Reorder the Variables factor to match the correct order
odds_ratio_data$Variables <- factor(odds_ratio_data$Variables, levels = correct_order)

# Create the odds ratio plot with confidence intervals and flip the coordinates
ggplot(odds_ratio_data, aes(x = Variables, y = OddsRatio)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3) +  # Plot odds ratios as points
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LowerCI_OR, ymax = UpperCI_OR), width = 0.2) +  # Error bars for confidence intervals
  coord_flip() +  # Flip coordinates for horizontal plot
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Odds Ratios from Logistic Regression Models Predicting Coresidence among Young Adults NLSY07,2005-2017",
       x = "Variables",
       y = "Odds Ratio") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),  # Center the title
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10))  # Ensure variable names are easy to read


Try + scale_x_discrete(limits = rev) (x as you use coord_flip). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391850/reverse-order-of-discrete-y-axis-in-ggplot2

Use a discrete scale, with limits = rev. This will apply the rev function to whatever limits you have.
Note that you do not have to use coord_flip anymore, so we can do:
ggplot(odds_ratio_data, aes(OddsRatio, Variables)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = LowerCI_OR, xmax = UpperCI_OR), width = 0.2) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)

